# What does this monotonicity condition on the gradient correspond to?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, definition, convex-optimization, monotone-functions

We know that all the gradient of convex functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}, X$ convex, are monotone maps, that is,

> $f$ convex, continuously differentiable $\implies (\nabla f(x) -
>  \nabla f(x^\prime)^T(x-x^\prime) \geq 0$

[Boyd Page 115 https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf]

We can make this statement stronger,

> $f$ strictly convex, cont. diff. $\implies (\nabla f(x) -
>  \nabla f(x^\prime)^T(x-x^\prime) > 0, \forall x$ such that $x \neq
>  x^\prime$
>
> $f$ strongly convex, cont. diff.$\implies (\nabla f(x) - \nabla
>  f(x^\prime)^T(x-x^\prime) \geq c\| x-x^\prime\|, c>0, \forall x,
>  x^\prime$

What about?

> $f$ ??? continuously diff.$\implies (\nabla f(x) - \nabla
>  f(x^\prime)^T(x-x^\prime) \geq -c\| x-x^\prime\|, c>0, \forall x,
>  x^\prime$

What condition must $f$ satisfy? Is this the case when $f$ is strongly concave?

Comment: You are missing squares on the norms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement on the right-hand side in the last box (with $||x-x'||^2$) is equivalent to $f + \frac c2 \,\|\cdot\|^2$ being convex.

Comment: What could be an example of such function?

Comment: $f \equiv 0$ or $f = c \, \|\cdot\|^2$ or (more generally) any smooth function whose Hessian is bounded from below (i.e., the smallest eigenvalue is bounded from below).